# Styling a cancellation line that depends on the length

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I don't know the value to go inside, so I need a cancellation line that changes depending on the length. 
 I tried the "text-decoration:line-through" property but could not because of the specified cancel line form. 
 Here are three questions I have. Should I use a virtual selector to make the above shape? Do I have to use the position:absolute property just by the shape of the arrow? Or is there any other way? 
I can't use a framework like jQuery, and I can only use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```css
.price {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.price::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #888888;
    border-right: 1px solid #888888;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="price">$200</div>
<div class="price">$20000</div>
<div class="price">$2000000</div>
<div class="price">$200000000</div>
<div class="price">$20000000000</div>
```